# how to print the greek, persian and spanish letters by using encode and decode?

Tags: python

I update the question since I fixed the first problem in my previous code.
But I still have another problem.
The Last elif does not work.It will always print "Not Found" When I want to translate from Greek to Spanish.
I think these problems are just in last 3 elif since i tried to translate reverse(greek to english or spanish to english or etc)
It will just give the correct answer when I input the first key and value

```
def translate(fm,to,word):
    en_sp={"bee":"abeja", "iguana":"iguana", "scorpion":"alacrán", "giraffe":"jirafa", "spider":"araña"}
    en_gr={"bee":"μέλισσα", "iguana":"ιγκουάνα", "scorpion":"σκορπιός", "giraffe":"καμηλοπάρδαλη", "spider":"αράχνη"}
    sp_gr={"abeja":"μέλισσα","iguana":"ιγκουάνα","alacrán":"σκορπιός","jirafa":"καμηλοπάρδαλη","araña":"αράχνη"}
    if((fm=="English" or fm=='ENG' or fm=='eng' or fm=='english' or fm=='ENGLISH' or fm=='Eng')and(to=="Spanish" or to=="SP" or to=="sp" or to=="Sp" or to=="spanish" or to=="SPANISH")):
        for i in en_sp:
            if(word in en_sp):
                print(en_sp[word])
                break
            else:
                print("Not Found")
                break
    elif((fm=="English" or fm=='ENG' or fm=='eng' or fm=='english' or fm=='ENGLISH' or fm=='Eng')and(to=="Greek" or to=="GR" or to=="gr" or to=="Gr" or to=="greek" or to=="GREEK")):
        for i in en_gr:
            if(word in en_gr):
                print(en_gr[word])
                break
            else:
                print("Not Found")
                break
    elif((fm=="Spanish" or fm=="SP" or fm=="sp" or fm=="Sp" or fm=="spanish" or fm=="SPANISH")and(to=="Greek" or to=="GR" or to=="gr" or to=="Gr" or to=="greek" or to=="GREEK")):
        for i in sp_gr:
            if(word in sp_gr):
                print(sp_gr[word])
                break
            else:
                print("Not Found")
                break
    elif((to=="English" or to=='ENG' or to=='eng' or to=='english' or to=='ENGLISH' or to=='Eng')and(fm=="Spanish" or fm=="SP" or fm=="sp" or fm=="Sp" or fm=="spanish" or fm=="SPANISH")):
        for i in en_sp:
            if(en_sp[i]==word):
                print(i)
                break
            else:
                print("Not Found")
                break
    elif((to=="English" or to=='ENG' or to=='eng' or to=='english' or to=='ENGLISH' or to=='Eng')and(fm=="Greek" or fm=="GR" or fm=="gr" or fm=="Gr" or fm=="greek" or fm=="GREEK")):
        for i in en_gr:
            if(en_gr[i]==word):
                print(i)
                break
            else:
                print("Not Found")
                break
    elif((to=="Spanish" or to=="SP" or to=="sp" or to=="Sp" or to=="spanish" or to=="SPANISH")and(fm=="Greek" or fm=="GR" or fm=="gr" or fm=="Gr" or fm=="greek" or fm=="GREEK")):
        for i in sp_gr:
            if(sp_gr[i]==word):
                print(i)
                break
            else:
                print("Not Found")
                break




def Menu():
    print("Please Choose The language you are going to translate from:\n\t 1)English\n\t 2)Spanish\n\t 3)Greek:\n")
    fm=input()
    print("Please Choose The language you are going to translate to:\n\t 1)English\n\t 2)Spanish\n\t 3)Greek:\n")
    to=input()
    print("Please Enter the word you are going to translate from ",fm," to ",to," :")
    word=input()
    translate(fm,to,word)



#if(fm=='English' or fm=='ENG' or fm=='eng' or fm=='english' or fm=='ENGLISH' or fm=='Eng'):
Menu()
```

Sample Output in the case that does not work:

```
Please Choose The language you are going to translate from:
     1)English
     2)Spanish
     3)Greek:

gr
Please Choose The language you are going to translate to:
     1)English
     2)Spanish
     3)Greek:

sp
Please Enter the word you are going to translate from  gr  to  sp  :
ιγκουάνα
Not Found
```

Comment: Encode and decode aren't just parameters for opening a file. They can be called on the strings themselves. If you're on Python 3.6+ UTF-8 encoding should already be in place. I can't reproduce that error with your code

Comment: so it means there is no problem in my code?

Comment: If you can get the letters to print to the terminal by themselves (`print("ιγκουάνα")`) then including it in a dictionary shouldn't make any difference

Comment: Actually my compiler doesnt print("ιγκουάνα")

Comment: That's odd, what compiler are you using? I can confirm it prints fine on [REPL.it](https://repl.it/OGoS/0)

Comment: I using python 3 (onlinegb)

Comment: Online GDB seems to be double-escaping special characters. Even when decoding or encoding, whenever printing it, it just escapes the string. I would try using a different environment.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code, just an environmental issue

Comment: yes sure I fix it, But it still have a tiny proble, I am going to update my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace your last 3 elif by below code
The code swap the keys and values and will work.
Good luck

Sample:

```
new_dict1 = dict (zip(en_sp.values(),en_sp.keys()))
for i in new_dict1:
    if(word in new_dict1):
        print(new_dict1[word])
        break
    else:
        print("Not Found")
        break
```

Comment: You're Welcome Kiarash!